# Use Linux Mint to access files from "Windows Subsystem for Linux” written by Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, multi-boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows installed on my `C:` drive,
and I have Ubuntu/Bash in Windows. 
I have a second partition with Linux Mint. 
On Windows bash I tried to use `fdisk -l` to see what partitions there are,
because I wanted to mount my Windows bash to my Linux Mint
so I could browse files without having to reboot the system.

Is this possible? and if yes, can someone please tell me how I could do this this? Because when I typed `fdisk -l` it said

```
fdisk: cannot open /proc/partitions: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu in Windows has access to the hardware. I use [ext2fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/files/) to browse Linux partitions from Windows by mounting with a drive letter. I've not used write mode much, but it works very well when a partition is mounted as read-only.

Comment: Not sure about Bash on Windows not being able to use `fdisk`, but I know WSL's file system is a virtual one built inside Windows' filesystem. So I doubt mounting it in real linux would be easy, and it may not be possible (yet?), but if you're looking to see the files in there, be careful not to edit/create things (yet?) as it breaks things, but you can view thing as described in answers to this question on [ubuntu.se]: [Where is the Ubuntu file system root directory in Windows Subsystem for Linux and vice versa?](https://askubuntu.com/q/759880/866475)

Comment: I'd suggest not to change/edit WSL files from any Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The virtualized filesystem of Windows Subsystem for Linux is inside a [.VHD file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/03/10/understanding-where-your-virtual-machine-files-are-hyper-v/) which can't be found by fdisk, but it can be connected to from within Linux Mint, as illustrated for multiple differing approaches, within the answers at https://askubuntu.com/questions/295155/how-do-i-mount-vhd-file. The more direct method requires Virtualbox and its Fuse subsystem:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo mkdir /mnt/vhd-disk/
sudo vdfuse -f disk.vhd /mnt/vhd-disk/
sudo mount -o loop  /mnt/vhd-disk/Partition1 /mnt/partition1
```

Comment: Why do you mention VHD file? OP installed Linux Mint as a dual boot.

Comment: He wants to access the files of Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: And WSL isn't also installed in VHD.